# Missing code coverage tab in VS localtestrun.testrunconfig?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am relatively new to unit testing and was attempting to add some code coverage to my unit tests. Yet i can't find the code coverage tab in Visual Studio 2008 in the localtestrun.testrunconfig, is there any missing Add-in or tool?

Thanks,
DMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand "Code Coverage" is available only in "bigger" editions of Visual Studio 2008. In other words, this feature is NOT available in the "Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition".

Which edition of Visual Studio 2008 are you using ?

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902.aspx#NotInPro)

Comment: yes i am using the Professional Edition which seems to be the problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu Test, select Edit test run configuration for your current test run and check enable code coverage. Then perform a run and then on the test run results you can choose to display code coverage.

Comment: I did as u said and the localtestrun.testrunconfig opened up again, the only tabs i can c are the General, Deployment, Hosts, Setups and Cleanup Scripts, and Test Timeouts. I can't see anything that references code coverage

Comment: Well there's supposed to be a Code Coverage tab between general and deployment...

Comment: That was my question in the first place, am i missing some sort of add-in or something as to why I cant see the code coverage tab?
Thanks,