# Code Coverage not listed in VS2008 - c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-coverage

I'm trying to do unit testing in visual studio 2008 (Proffesional Edition). I've create a class library solution for this topic. Now, I want to use the feature of "Code coverage" but this is not listed in my local test config.

local config:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone knows how to listed and enable?
I'd appreciate any comments/suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: I thought that Code Coverage was only added to VS2010, so it's just not there for 2008.

Comment: Click on the [Download button](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7940) and locate your edition in the chart.  The outcome is somewhat predictable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys!
First of all thank you.

But this "issue" has been asked before :(, and yes, Code Coverage is available for Visual Studio 2008, but only for "bigger" editions, and not for Professional Edition.

Please see the next link of [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902.aspx#NotInPro). But also see the next links to stackoverflow questions, [Question#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064909/missing-code-coverage-tab-in-vs-localtestrun-testrunconfig), and [Question#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900582/code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2008-pro).

Thanks